# How to provide per-row parameters to JDBI Mapper?

Tags: java, jdbi

With an inlined lambda, it is easy to pass additional parameters to a mapper:

```
int importantThing = 1234;

h.createQuery("SELECT * FROM somewher").map(
    (int idx, ResultSet rs, StatementContext ctx) -> new Thing(rs, importantThing)
).list()...
```

But I would care to change this to the declarative form of defining the mapper through an annotation, as I don't want to have to repeat the above everywhere I want me some ThingS. Is there a way to delcare a ResultMapper in a way that would allow me to provide additional parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is not possible out of the box, at least with JDBI2.
Annotation-based mapper instance can be created by JDBI using no-args constructor only.